# How to connect Raspberry Pi Pico W to MQTT Broker using C/C++?

Tags: c++, mqtt, iot, raspberry-pi-pico

I´m trying to connect Raspberry Pi Pico W to a MQTT broker like HiveMQ but I can only find ways to make it using python, can anyone help me to get this connection using C/C++.

I have some examples that the documentation on the Raspsberry Pi Pico W gave me, but I´m not able to understand what are the purpouse of anything or how to get the connection I want. The examples are on this repo https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/pico_w

I tried using the arduino firmware bur I can´t seem to find the correct traduction to bare C/C++ coding from arduino code. I used the Adafruit_MQTT_Client library of arduin to connect to Adafruit IO, and it works correctly with raspberry pi pico w but I need help with the conversion from arduino to C/C++

Comment: Arduino code is C++

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Eclipse Paho MQTT Client, they support C language.
https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=downloads.php